# Implementing conditional execution in Python

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

I found abandoned [project](https://github.com/jruizgit/rules) on GitHub and curious is it possible to implement part of it on just Python?

Here is most close [example of processing](https://github.com/jruizgit/rules/blob/master/README.md#python-2) I would like to implement:

```py
from durable.lang import *

with ruleset('test'):
    @when_all(m.subject.matches('3[47][0-9]{13}'))
    def amex(c):
        print ('Amex detected {0}'.format(c.m.subject))

    @when_all(m.subject.matches('4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?'))
    def visa(c):
        print ('Visa detected {0}'.format(c.m.subject))

    @when_all(m.subject.matches('(5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|2720)[0-9]{12}'))
    def mastercard(c):
        print ('Mastercard detected {0}'.format(c.m.subject))

assert_fact('test', { 'subject': '375678956789765' })
assert_fact('test', { 'subject': '4345634566789888' })
assert_fact('test', { 'subject': '2228345634567898' })
```

**Goal**:

- Call functions only under some condition.
- Track matches and inner function execution in uniformed way.
- Reuse variables from the same scope to be more flexible with inner functions calls.

I have [PoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912078/is-there-a-better-way-of-conditional-execution-in-python) working, but I wonder is any better **algorithmic** approach to do the same in Python? Most obvious way to do something similar to bellow code. But is there more elegant way to get rid of repeating `if ...: processed = True` pattern and have this code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

```py
def boo(a, c):
  # do something
  return True

def foo(a, b, c):
  # do something more
  return True

def setup(a, b, c):
   processed = False
   matched = False

   if a == "boo" and c == 1:
      matched = True
      processed = bool(boo(a, c))

   if a == "boo" and (c == 2 or b == 3):
      matched = True
      processed = bool(foo(a, b, c))
   ...

   if not matched:
      logger.warning("Couldn't match any rule")

   return processed
```

Comment: Hey welcome to Code Review! It looks like your linked Stack Overflow post contains the actual code you want reviewed and what you've posted here is just the alternative code if you were doing it by hand is that right? In that case you actually need to post the code you want reviewed here rather than linking to it. Also edit your post to say _why_ you want this at all, what problem does it solve? That will provide the necessary context to say whether your solution is suitable and how it might be improved.

Comment: (The *something* most *similar* to *bellow* should be to *bark*…?!;)

Comment: @Greedo I'm not sure which one is better approach. I added an example to clarify idea.

Comment: @greybeard oh, well. Thanks for catching this. I added missing noun.

Comment: Code review is for code that you wrote and that you know is working. This question seems to indicate that someone else wrote the code and that you don't have it working the way you want to yet.

Comment: @pacmaninbw that's wrong assumption.

Comment: Also, why it was marked as off-topic. Could someone explain please?

Comment: Here is the [help page for on-topic questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: 5 people closed the question, however, the moderator changed the reason for closure and became the only person to close the question (makes 6 people that closed the question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128933/discussion-between-su1tan-and-pacmaninbw).

Comment: (It's rather that `bellow` isn't anything like the opposite of *above* - *below* is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bitwise Operators**

While your use of bitwise operators works fine as far as I can tell, I wouldn't expect them to be used like this in Python. So instead of

```
if ((a == "boo") & ((c == 2) | (b == 3))):
```

I'd prefer

```
if a == "boo" and (c == 2 or b == 3):
```

Also note that you don't need as many parantheses.

---

**`processed = True`**

```
if boo(a, c):
     processed = True
```

can be replaced by

```
processed = boo(a, c)
```

as long as `boo` (or any other relevant function) returns a `bool`. If it returns something else you can convert it to a `bool` explicitly:

```
processed = bool(boo(a, c))
```

---

**EDIT:**

- You do not need `matched`, simply use an `if - elif - else`-construct
- You *can* replace `processed` by storing the matching function call in a variable. I'm not sure if you should though.

```
from functools import partial


def setup(a, b, c):
    function_call = lambda: False

    if a == "boo" and c == 1:
        function_call = partial(boo, a, c)  # alt: lambda: boo(a, c)
    elif a == "boo" and (c == 2 or b == 3):
        function_call = partial(foo, a, b, c)  # alt: lambda: foo(a, b, c)
    else:
        logger.warning("Couldn't match any rule")

    return bool(function_call())
```

Comment: thanks! But there is a problem: I don't want to be dependent on inner function implementation. Also, if I want to track matches together with function return? Adding more `matched = True` in each step? (sorry, for not being more specific at the beginning)

Comment: I updated my original question with your proposal. But the code is not as DRY as it could be...

Comment: In general, please refrain from editing suggestions from answers into your existing question. Prefer posting a new question with the updated code. I've included some pointers for decreasing repetition in your edited code.

Comment: Thanks for `partial` hint!